# How to sort items in Qtreeview in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

How to sort items in QTreeview by the following concepts ?

- Ascending Order ( From A to Z, 0 to 9)
- Descending Order ( From Z to A , 9 to 0)
- Given Order or Original order  by user ( From A to Z )
- Reverse Order of Original Order ( From Z to A)

```
self.model_01 = self.model()
for i in range(self.model_01.rowCount()):
    if self.itemData(i) is None:
        self.setItemData(i, i)

...


def ascending_order(self):
    self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.DisplayRole)
    self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(), Qt.AscendingOrder)


def descending_order(self):
    self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.DisplayRole)
    self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(), Qt.DescendingOrder)


def given_order(self):
    print("given order")
    self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.UserRole)
    self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(), Qt.AscendingOrder)


def reverse_order(self):
    print("reverse order")
    self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.UserRole)
    self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(), Qt.DescendingOrder)
```

using this code , I can able to sort item in ascending order as well as in descending order in Qt.DisplayRole.

But in Qt.UserRole, I cant able to sort items.

How to sort items in ascending(Original order) or in reverse of original order  ?

**Update - Minimal reproducible example**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

data = {
    "select all": {
        'Group 1': ['item11', 'item12'],
        'Group 3': ['item32', 'item31'],
        'Group 2': ['item21', 'item22'],
        'Group 4': ['item41', 'item42'],
    }
}
class MyModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.root_text, self.parent_text, self.child_text = [], [], []

        for root_key, root_value in data.items():
            if root_key not in self.root_text:
                self.root_text.append(root_key)
            root_item = QStandardItem()
            root_item.setData(root_key, role=Qt.DisplayRole)
            root_item.setCheckable(True)
            self.appendRow(root_item)

            for parent_key, parent_value in root_value.items():
                if parent_key not in self.parent_text:
                    self.parent_text.append(parent_key)
                parent_item = QStandardItem()
                parent_item.setData(parent_key, role=Qt.DisplayRole)
                parent_item.setCheckable(True)
                root_item.appendRow(parent_item)

                for child_value in parent_value:
                    if child_value not in self.child_text:
                        self.child_text.append(child_value)
                    child_item = []
                    child_item = QStandardItem()
                    child_item.setData(child_value, role=Qt.DisplayRole)
                    child_item.setCheckable(True)
                    parent_item.appendRow(child_item)

        self.itemChanged.connect(self.update_children)

    def update_children(self, item, fromUser=True):
        print(item,"item")
        if fromUser:
            # temporarily disconnect to avoid recursion
            self.itemChanged.disconnect(self.update_children)
        for i in range(item.rowCount()):
            child = item.child(i)
            child.setCheckState(item.checkState())
            # explicitly call update_children
            self.update_children(child, False)

        if fromUser:
            root = self.invisibleRootItem()
            parent = item.parent() or root
            while True:
                count = parent.rowCount()
                checked = 0
                for i in range(count):
                    state = parent.child(i).checkState()
                    if state == Qt.Checked:
                        checked += 1
                    elif state == Qt.PartiallyChecked:
                        parent.setCheckState(Qt.PartiallyChecked)
                        break
                else:
                    if not checked:
                        parent.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
                    elif checked == count:
                        parent.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
                    else:
                        parent.setCheckState(Qt.PartiallyChecked)

                if parent == root:
                    break
                parent = parent.parent() or root

            self.itemChanged.connect(self.update_children)

class MyCombo(QComboBox):
    clickedData = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setView(self.treeView)
        self.treeView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        # Qmenu intilize
        self.menu = QMenu()
         
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.cntxt_menu)
        self.RightClickMenu()

        self.delegate = QStyledItemDelegate(self.treeView)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
                event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress
                and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton
        ):
            index = self.treeView.indexAt(event.pos())

            if index.isValid():
                opt = self.treeView.viewOptions()
                opt.rect = self.treeView.visualRect(index)
                self.delegate.initStyleOption(opt, index)
                checkRect = self.style().subElementRect(
                    QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator, opt, self.treeView)
                if checkRect.contains(event.pos()):
                    self.clickedData = index, checkRect
        elif event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.clickedData:
                index = self.treeView.indexAt(event.pos())
                pressIndex, checkRect = self.clickedData
                if index == pressIndex and event.pos() in checkRect:
                    state = index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
                    if state == Qt.Checked:
                        state = Qt.Unchecked
                    else:
                        state = Qt.Checked
                    self.model().setData(index, state, Qt.CheckStateRole)
                self.clickedData = None
            return True
        elif (
                event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress
                and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton
        ):
            index = self.treeView.indexAt(event.pos())
            state = index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
            if state == Qt.Checked:
                state = Qt.Unchecked
            else:
                state = Qt.Checked
            self.model().setData(index, state, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self.treeView.viewport().update()
            self.clickedData = None
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def showPopup(self):
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        width = self.treeView.sizeHintForColumn(0)
        maxCount = self.maxVisibleItems()
        index = self.model().index(0, 0, self.rootModelIndex())
        visible = 0
        while index.isValid():
            visible += 1
            index = self.treeView.indexBelow(index)
            if visible > maxCount:
                # the visible count is higher than the maximum, so the vertical
                # scroll bar will be shown and we have to consider its width.
                # Note that this does NOT consider styles that use "transient"
                # scroll bars, which are shown *within* the content of the view,
                # as it happens on macOs; see QStyle.styleHint() and
                # QStyle::SH_ScrollBar_Transient
                width += self.treeView.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()
                break
        self.treeView.setMinimumWidth(width)
        super().showPopup()

    def RightClickMenu(self):
        self.menu.clear()
        self.ascending_action = QAction('Ascending',self)
        self.menu.addAction(self.ascending_action)
        self.ascending_action.triggered.connect(self.ascending_order)

        self.descending_action = QAction('Descending')
        self.descending_action.triggered.connect(self.descending_order)
        self.menu.addAction(self.descending_action)

        self.original_action = QAction('Original Order')
        self.original_action.triggered.connect(self.original_order)
        self.menu.addAction(self.original_action)

        self.reverse_action = QAction('Reverse order')
        self.reverse_action.triggered.connect(self.reverse_order)
        self.menu.addAction(self.reverse_action)

    def cntxt_menu(self,pos):
        self.model_01 = self.model()
        self.menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def ascending_order(self):
        self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(),Qt.AscendingOrder)

    def descending_order(self):
        self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(), Qt.DescendingOrder)

    def original_order(self):
        print("given order")
        self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.UserRole)
        # self.model_01.sort(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model_01.sort(0,Qt.AscendingOrder)


    def reverse_order(self):
        print("reverse order")
        self.model_01.setSortRole(Qt.UserRole)
        self.model_01.sort(self.modelColumn(), Qt.DescendingOrder)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("QCombobox")
        self.comboBox = MyCombo()
        self.comboBox.setEditable(False)
        self.model = MyModel()
        self.comboBox.setModel(self.model)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.comboBox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you would need to set the userData for each of the items in your model to the index they were originally given when added to the model.

Comment: Please add more details to the question: 1. The initial snippet seems to be part of a QComboBox, and its relation to the question is unclear; 2. Even assuming you're using the model of the combo, what is the point of using a QTreeView? 3. What model are you using? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante. Based on your previous answer of my question , I try to sort the item in ascending, descending, Original order and reverse of orignal order. Every thing as on your code.  and I just add Contextmenu and try to sort it.

Comment: @Rithik I suppose you're referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75141653/2001654), but, still: 1. questions should be self-contained, and if you're referring to another post, you should make people aware of that, or at least provide some context; 2. we see *hundreds* of posts a week, you cannot hope we remember all of them or their authors; 3. in that answer, sorting was **never** considered. That said, without any valid [mre], we cannot really help you: for what we know, you may even trying to set those user roles before filling the whole model. And what about child sorting?

Comment: @musicamante, add M.R.E code block

Comment: @Rithik Ok, for future reference, please try to put more efforts in providing a MRE: it's now clear that your issue is just about sorting a model, and the whole QComboBox/QTreeView is quite irrelevant; your example would have been sufficient using a standard model with a tree view. While, as explained in my answer, there could be some indirect issues related to multiple views and complex models, you could have just mentioned the related post: those issues could have eventually been addressed afterwards. The whole point of a MRE (emphasis on *minimal*) is to allow us to *focus on the problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt already provides such a mechanism with standard views: both [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#sortByColumn) and [QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#sortByColumn) provide a `sortByColumn()` function. The assumption is, as long as the model supports it (as explained in the docs), using `-1` for the column should *revert* to the original layout.

Unfortunately, while it generally works on QTableView, it seems that there is some inconsistency with QTreeView and QStandardItemModel (I did some basic testing, but I have not been able to find the cause yet; there is a couple of reports in the Qt bug report system, but they seem to be still unresolved).

Not all is lost, though: as long as the insertion order is consistent (see the notes below), we can use a custom user role whenever a new item is added to the model, including the very first item of any parent (including top level ones).

In order to do that, we need to connect the [`rowsInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal *before* any item (row) is created, and properly set the user role starting from the `first` row up to the last one of the row count of the parent (in order to correctly update the indexes of all following items in case an item is *inserted*).

```py
class MyModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rowsInserted.connect(self.updateInsertionOrder)
        # ...

    def updateInsertionOrder(self, parent, first, last):
        with QSignalBlocker(self):
            for row in range(first, self.rowCount(parent)):
                self.setData(self.index(row, 0, parent), row, Qt.UserRole)
```

Note that:

- the above is obviously valid only as long as the *first* column is considered for sorting: calling `sort()` using a column higher than the first will obviously not work; eventually consider to implement a custom function (eg. `sortByInsertionOrder`) that will always call `sort()` with the first column index;
- the implementation assumes that new items are always added based on the *current* sorting: if `sort()` is called with different arguments (the sort role is not `UserRole`, the column is not 0 or the order is descending) and a new item is *inserted* supposing the current sorting, the "original" order will not be consistent: for instance, if the current order is descending and uses the display role and you *insert* an item at row 0 because it would theoretically follow the current sorting, the result is that the `UserRole` of any (currently) following indexes will be rewritten, thus losing the original order; a more consistent approach would be to actually use a QSortFilterProxyModel for the view, and apply the sorting to that;
- I did not add any support for moving rows or row removal; use a similar approach using the related signals (`rowsMoved` and `rowsRemoved`) in case that becomes necessary;
- QStandardItemModel has a further [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#QStandardItemModel-1) that allows to set the model *size* before actually adding/setting any item; if you want to add support for such case, you have to check the model rowcount *before* doing anything and, in case it *does* have rows, call the above function above accordingly: `self.updateInsertionOrder(QModelIndex(), 0, self.rowCount() - 1)`;